# HTML table in a render array?

Tags: 7, theming

I dislike the notion of using something like this since it may mean I have to commit my table data straight to HTML sooner than I want to:

```
$render_array = array(
    'maintable' => array(
        '#markup' = theme_table($table)
    ),
    ...
);
```

Do I have an option to pass the table data into the render array (as opposed to rendering it immediately to HTML), by chance?

Comment: Why do you dislike it?

Comment: I just edited that part in.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$render_array['maintable'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
);
```

Comment: Oh, so that works?

Comment: of course :) examples: contact_category_list(), dblog_overview(), dblog_top(), etc